# Mapbox GL JS Updating Source of Image Overlay

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geospatial, mapbox-gl-js

I am working on a project where I have 4 maps on the screen at once. I have a barebones menu where the user selects an overlay, and it displays on the correct map.

This works, however the image sources for the image overlays I am using update server-side every 2 minutes. I would like to just have a simple function to re-fetch the source automatically so it's guaranteed to be updated every 2 minutes. I have added an image to show how this works.

I have found Mapbox API documentation on updating GeoJSON files in this manner, but I cannot figure out how to update *image sources* automatically. I have looked to no avail.

Here is my screenshot with actual source and layer, and below that I will write pseudocode for what I am looking to do.

[image: Edited Screenshot]

Here is the **Source and Layer**:

```
topleftmapbox.on('load', function() {
  topleftmapbox.addSource("source_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY", {
    "type": "image",
    "url": "images/KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY.gif",
    "coordinates": [

      [-103.009641, 33.911],
      [-94.009641, 33.911],
      [-94.009641, 24.911],
      [-103.009641, 24.911]
    ]
  })

  var layers = topleftmapbox.getStyle().layers;
  // Find the index of the first symbol layer in the map style
  var firstSymbolId;
  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    if (layers[i].type === 'symbol') {
      firstSymbolId = layers[i].id;
      break;
    }
  }

  topleftmapbox.addLayer({
    "id": "overlay_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY",
    "source": "source_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY",
    "type": "raster",
    "raster-opacity": 0.5,
    "layout": {
      "visibility": "none"
    },
  }, firstSymbolId)
});
```

**Pseudocode for what I would like to do:**

```
On Map load() {
  start timer for every 2 minutes
  Get Source "source_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY"
  Refresh the source with same URL ("images/KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY.gif") to make sure its live.
  keep doing this every 2 minutes
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (now?) an `updateImage()` method so you can do:

```
map.getSource('source_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY').updateImage({
  url: "images/KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY.gif?" + counter++,
  coordinates': [
    [-103.009641, 33.911],
    [-94.009641, 33.911],
    [-94.009641, 24.911],
    [-103.009641, 24.911]
  ]
});
```

Including an incrementing `counter` will ensure you're not displaying a cached image.

Comment: try the following to update the source image: map.getSource('yourSource').updateImage({url: `yourUrl`});